# ROS in multi-robot applications?

Tags: multi-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Greetings,
In my knowledge, most development in ROS is for single robot operations.
Is ROS being used in any multi-robot applications?
Any open-source initiatives which focuses on multi-robot systems?

Edit 1:
Are there any released / beta packages involving Multi-robots *e.g*. exploration, tracking *etc*?

prince

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39463/ros-in-multi-robot-applications?/) by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on ROS Answers with karma: 660 on 2012-07-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Searching on answers.ros.org gives a few results:

- [tag multi-robots](http://answers.ros.org/questions/scope:all/sort:activity-desc/tags:multi-robot/page:1/)
- [tag multi_robots](http://answers.ros.org/questions/scope:all/sort:activity-desc/tags:multi_robot/page:1/)

So I guess people are definitely working on multi-robot applications.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-07-23**:
multimaster is also relevant: http://answers.ros.org/questions/scope:all/sort:activity-desc/query:multimaster/page:1/